# Why does selecting text in one TextView in ViewPager cause the system to think it is selected in another TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, textselection

I have a ViewPager with three TextViews that I update on change to make a book with three pages in memory (this page, prev page, and next page).  What I'm sometimes seeing is when I select a word in the current TextView, it thinks I am selecting it in the previous page's TextView, which is not even visible.

I assume this is some sort of limitation in Android that I have to work around, by reminding something that I'm selecting text in a new TextView, because even though it selects a single word in the visible TextView, it gives me the text in the textview to the left of the screen instead, whatever would have been in the exact same part of the screen as the text I am selecting.

Does anyone know how to remind it to use the current textview?